# Winforms: Resizing user controls in form control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Context:

I'm trying to build a form using [Microsoft Prism guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx).

I have two user controls that get injected into a form.
The form contains two panels that represent the containers which will hold the user controls.

The user controls get inject at run time via DI (I'm using the MVP pattern which is similar to MVVM but tweaked for Winforms).

The form has a default minimum size but the maximum size was not specified. The only way to resize the form is to make it fullscreen. It has the AutoSize property set to TRUE and the AutoSizeMode set to GrowAndShrink

Both user controls have the AutoSize set to TRUE.
All the containers inside the user controls have the AutoSize property set to TRUE, DOCK set to FILL and AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink. The maximum size for a control is not set.

The panels inside the the form are stacked one under another and have the Anchor property set to: TOP, LEFT,RIGHT, respectively: BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT.

Problem:

When resizing the form to fullscreen, I would expect that the user control to expand to fill the entire screen.

That is not happening.

The user controls do not change in size and I can't figure out a reason for it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

If I change the DOCK property of the panels inside the form to TOP, respectively 
FILL, the panel will get resized, but the user controls inside the panels remain unchanged.

Comment: You are giving a bunch of conflicting layout directions, Anchor resizes, Dock resizes, AutoScale resizes, what is actually supposed to happen?  If these UCs need to scale proportionally then use a TableLayoutPanel that's docked to fill.

Comment: I mentioned all the layout setting because so that someone can point out some obvious mistake. The end goal is to be able to inject two custom controls in a form at run-time, dynamically,  that are re-sizing properly. Any that works, and doesn't need extra code is welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about setting Dock and AutoSizeMode on your controls—just use Anchor and you will find it works just fine.

I never use `AutoSize = true`. I always have it at `false` (as a matter of fact I had to check some of my forms to verify that the `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode` properties even existed on controls on my forms).

In the scenario you describe, I would have the Anchor set to Top, Left, Bottom, Right, both for the panels and the controls contained within.

Comment: Setting the anchor to top, left,botton,right for poth panels will overlap the panels. If I where to set TOP, LEFT, RIGHT for the first one and BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT for the second one it will not resize accordingly. Setting all the anchors for the control did not worl, however, as @Schlinger suggested, setting the DOCK to FILL solved part of my problem, i.e. the user controls are filling the form like they should, but the controls inside them are not resize. Maybe it has something to due with the fact that I'm using a FlowLayout as main container for the user controls?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Dock` of the control in the panel also to `Fill`.

Comment: It did re-sized the user controls added in the form, however the content of the user control did not scale. I'm using a FlowLayout as a container for all the user controls used inside my custom control. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Set the Anchor Properties of the controls which should resize on the usercontrol. Example: When a textbox should go right when u expand the form to right set the anchors TOP,LEFT and RIGHT

Comment: Tried setting the suggested anchors for panel. Did not work. Maybe because it is inside a FlowLayout control and I use the flow break property    ? I don't want other user controls on the same row as the panel.

Comment: You must set the anchors on the controls like TextBoxes, Buttons, Labels etc.

Comment: [Image](http://snag.gy/OTwci.jpg). Here's how the UI looks. On the left, you ca see what is the user control made of. The numbered controls all have the Anchror property set to TOP, LEFT,RIGTH. All of them work as expected, except for control 7. When I pull control 7 (in the designer) to the right, I would expect control 3 and 1 to move to the right, but that is not happening. If I try to pull control 4, control 7 will follow. I made the same settings and it should work. The only thing that is different is that I am using a flowLayout Panel instead on a normal panel.

Comment: Just tested how the controls with anchors inside a flow layout behave. The anchors are disregarded. That's what generated my problem. Thank you!